# How to query pdf page size from the command line?

Tags: pdf

For scripting I need to get the page dimensions of a PDF file (in mm).

`pdfinfo` just prints it in 'pts', e.g.:

```
Page size:      624 x 312 pts
```

What should I use?

Or what unit is 'pts' anyway - in case I want to convert them ...

Comment: [Point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_(typography)) on Wikipedia

Comment: Which page did you want the size of? The legal size outer cover? The leaflet size "this page is intentionally blank"? The letter size double pages?

Comment: I'd never heard of pdfinfo, thank you :) That shows more info as of 2023

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The 'pts' unit used by `pdfinfo` denotes a PostScript point. A [PostScript point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_%28typography%29) is defined in terms of an inch and a resolution of 72 dots per inch:

> In the late 1980s to the 1990s, the traditional point was supplanted by the desktop publishing point (also called the PostScript point), which was defined as 72 points to the inch (**1 point** = 1⁄72 inches = 25.4⁄72 mm = **0.352¯7 mm** [ ≙ **0.3528 mm**] ).

The manual to `gv` contains [a list of common paper formats](http://www.gnu.org/software/gv/manual/html_node/Paper-Keywords-and-paper-size-in-points.html) specified in PostScript points.

Comment: on common paper formats: `pdfinfo` sometimes gives me the paper format (like `Page size:      595.28 x 841.89 pts (A4)`) — I wonder if it does that for a list of page sizes it knows about?

Comment: A point is actually 0.352777777... mm, so **0.3528 mm** is a closer approximation.

Comment: For the strange case of page sizes being different throughout a document, if wanting the page size for, say, page 3: `pdfinfo foo.pdf -f 3 -l 3 | grep Page`

Comment: Note: If `pdfinfo`'s `Page rot` contains `90`, the `Page size` values need to be exchanged. With `identify` this isn't needed and in addition it returns the page size of all pages separately.

Comment: @maxschlepzig I found this helpful. Thank you. Where did you find that quote?

Comment: @PeterBergman It's from a [2012 revision of the linked wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Point_(typography)&oldid=494467355) (2nd paragraph)

Answer (score 21):

Not the easiest way, but given `imagemagick` and `units` you could also use

```
$ identify -verbose some.pdf | grep "Print size" 
Print size: 8.26389x11.6944
```

to find the page size in inches (this may yield several results if the PDF uses different dimensions) and then convert the numbers like this:

```
$ units -t '8.26389 inch' 'mm'
  209.90281
```

Meaning that 8.26 inches are 209.9 mm (I used an A4 PDF for this).

Comment: When I `identify` a PDF on OS X I don't get any output.

Comment: very late, but `identify` requires ImageMagick

Comment: This game me more than one size across about 20 lines.

Answer (score 7):

Came across the same problem and came to the following solution.
I didn't get into the documentation of how pdf files are constructed I just compared two empty pdf files with different page sizes.

It looks like pdfs have all kinds of attributes embedded between "<<" and ">>". I found that the page size info is there in plain text and can be found with a simple regex search.

This may or may not be true to all pdfs but it worked on all I could find from different sources.

The relevant part can look like any of these for a size A4 page:

```
/MediaBox [0 0 595 842]
/MediaBox[0 0 595 842]
/MediaBox[ 0 0 595.32 841.92]
```

It means [0 0 width height] so here is my super lame but working solution to extract this:

```
cat test.pdf | egrep -ao "/MediaBox ?\[ ?[0-9]+ [0-9]+ [0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)? [0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?\]" | head -1
```

Just change test.pdf to your file.

Comment: note that the values returned by this are in "points" not mm, pixels or inches

Answer (score 3):

I used maxchlepzigs answer to calculate the mm directly:

`$ pdfinfo test.pdf | grep "Page size" | grep -Eo '[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+' | awk -v x=0.3528 '{print $1*x}'`

this also works with Alex Knaufs answer but identify takes much longer than pdfinfo and requires imagemagick, the upside though is that you can use this for multiple files (ie by cd'ing into a directory and using `*.pdf`):

`$ identify -verbose some.pdf | grep "Print size" | grep -Eo '[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+' | awk -v x=25.4 '{print $1*x}'`

The second `grep` command gets the two point/inch values. I'm fairly sure you can skip the grep regex and do it directly with awk but i couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately `pdfinfo` gives the size of the first page only. We can use `mutool` to get sizes from all (or some chosen) pages. Then use `awk` to show these page sizes in millimeters.

```bash
mutool info -M file.pdf \
 | awk '/\[ [ .[:digit:]]+ \]/ { printf "Page %02d: %9s x %-9s\n",  $1, $8*25.4/72 "mm", $9*25.4/72 "mm" }'
Page 01:     841mm x 1189mm   
Page 02:     594mm x 841mm    
Page 03:     420mm x 594mm    
Page 04:     297mm x 420mm    
Page 05:     210mm x 297mm    
Page 06:     148mm x 210mm    
Page 07:     105mm x 148mm    
Page 08:    1000mm x 1414mm   
Page 09:     707mm x 1000mm   
Page 10:     500mm x 707mm    
Page 11:     353mm x 500mm    
Page 12:     250mm x 353mm    
Page 13:     176mm x 250mm    
Page 14:     125mm x 176mm    
Page 15:  184.15mm x 266.7mm  
Page 16:   215.9mm x 355.6mm  
Page 17:   215.9mm x 279.4mm
```

`mutool` returns page-sizes in [`pts`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_%28typography%29), defined as 1⁄72 of an international inch. Note that `1 in = 25.4 mm`.

#### Creating PDF file with pages of different sizes

`file.pdf` was created using `mutool` and `pdfjam` with the following bash script

```bash
#!/bin/bash

#Creating pdf file with an empty A4 (595 x 842 pts) page. 
mutool create -o empty.pdf /dev/null

#Using empty.pdf as template for creating 17 diferents page sizes
for PAPERSIZE in {letter,legal,executive,{a,b}{0..6}}paper; do 
    pdfjam -q --paper "${PAPERSIZE}" -o "${PAPERSIZE}.pdf" empty.pdf 
done

#Merging in file.pdf
mutool merge -o file.pdf *paper.pdf
```

Comment: In what units are the dimensions specified in a list such as `[ 0 0 2383.937 3370.394 ]`?

Comment: `pdfinfo` can get you page sizes of all the pages: `pdfinfo -f 1 -l $(pdfinfo "$file" | awk '/Pages/ {print $2}') "$file" | grep "Page.*size"`

Comment: This doesn't work if multiple pages in the PDF use the same mediabox. For example one PDF I tested has 5 pages, but only 3 mediaboxes are returned by mutool

Comment: @MilanSimek Yes, `mutool` shows each page where the mediabox size changes. This is not a bug, but rather a concise way to provide information on all pages.

Comment: @lezambranof It's definitely not a bug but a feature, I agree :) But it does mean the info provided by your `awk` command isn't correct in this case. For example with these page dimensions: `p1 100x100`, `p2 100x100`, `p3 200x200`, the command will return `Page 01 100x100`, `Page 02 200x200` which is obviously not correct